# Enthought Canopy IDE window zoomed too far(Windows 10)

Tags: ide, enthought, canopy

Installed Enthought Canopy IDE Python 2.7 for Windows 64 bit but IDE window is zoomed out too far. Control ++ and Control Shift ++ are not working in IDE on windows. What are the key options to fix this.
Welcome Screen and Package Manger both are zoomed far out.

Comment: Do you mean the magnification of the entire window, or the font size in one of the panels (editor or python)? What Canopy version? (from welcome screen or About command in Help menu)

Comment: Try Ctrl + mouse wheel. This is not a good question for stack overflow.

Comment: Version of Enthought Canopy is 2.1.6 and also tried with version  1.7.4. Ctrl + mouse wheel did not work. It is about magnification of the window. It is too small to view anything.

Comment: Re appropriateness for Stack Overflow -- I agree that this question is certainly not about programming per se, but Canopy is a programming tool (specifically, an IDE), and "how to use programming tools" is a topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User submitted a support ticket with screen shots. For the record, this is nothing about zooming or windows magnification.

There were two windows that don't display nicely when filling a full screen -- one had been accidentally maximized, the other had been accidentally resized to fill the full screen (same dimensions as maximized). So there was lots of extra fill space in each of these windows. The solution was to return them to their expected size, by unmaximizing / restoring in the first case, and by resizing in the second case.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: For the record, user clarified that this is not about zooming, but about support for hi-resolution displays. Canopy 2.1 does not yet support such displays, so icons and other GUI components are too small for comfort. The only workaround for now is to reduce display resolution.

Comment: Thanks. As the editor is displaying properly, this should be fine.